# How can I flip/invert my screen horizantally without a second monitor

Tags: display, software-rec

I know there are other posts on this subject but with my situation its a bit different. I cant use ultramon since I don't have a second monitor, and dummy dongle is not an option in my scenario. It would also be convenient if I could horizontally invert my mouse aswell because the purpose of this is so when I play a 3D game it gives the illusion the map is inverted.

Answer (score 0):

To rotate your screen, hit the Ctrl + Alt + right/left arrow keys at the same time. To flip your screen, hit the Ctrl + Alt + up/down arrow keys at the same time. Hold down and press the Ctrl + Alt + Up arrow. Holding down and pressing these keys will rotate your screen to its default position, which is the horizontal orientation.

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified, I'm running on Windows 10 so these shortcuts dont work. And I meant invert, not rotate. Thanks for your help though.